# Editing GIF in C#

Tags: c#, animation, frame, gif

How do I get the duration (playing time) of a GIF animation?

Here is my code:

```
GifTime = PoczatkowyGIF.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Time); 
//GifTime is a double; PoczatkowyGIF is my gif image.
```

`GifTime` isn't accurate. My animation is 3.8s, but `GifTime` is 3.9s. Another animation I tried was 0.88s, but `GifTime` was 0. So how do I get the animation time?  Also, how do I edit the GIF's first frame time and add a frame with a specified time to the existing GIF?

Comment: Why are you worried about a 0.01 second difference.  How did you calculate the lenght of the animation?

Comment: I used Easy Gif Animator for it. An when I add times of each frame (I made the animation in photoshop) it equals 3.8.
But ok, lets skip this question and answer the second one... If the program will work correctly, my code for counting durations was right.

Comment: I don't see another question to be honest.

Comment: How do I edit the GIF's first frame time and add a frame with a specified time to the existing GIF?

Answer (score 5):

In the following snippet, you can see how to calculate the total duration, accumulating the duration of each frame:

```
for (int f = 0; f < frameCount; f++)
{
  this_delay = BitConverter.ToInt32(image.GetPropertyItem(20736).Value, index) * 10;
  // Minimum delay is 100 ms
  delay += (this_delay < 100 ? 100 : this_delay);  
  index += 4;
}
```

Note that a frame duration can't be shorter than 100ms, and that may account for your calculation differences.

You can read [this post](http://madskristensen.net/post/examine-animated-gife28099s-in-c) about examining a .GIF, where you can find the rest of the code.

Also, to edit the last frame of an animated image, you can use

```
gifImage.SelectActiveFrame(dimension, first_frame_index);
```

`SelectActiveFrame` will allow you to edit the image, altering that specified (first in your case) frame.

I am not completely sure about this, but the framework does not have support for adding frames, I used [MagickNet](http://midimick.com/magicknet/) to re-encode a new GIF for this purpose. You may also want to take a look at [NGif](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11505/NGif-Animated-GIF-Encoder-for-NET) as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

The following code is a class for Creating, Opening or Editing Gifs.

It can't read the playtime from a stream, but for the second part of your question, it can write a Gif Animation with specified Delay on each Frame.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

/// <summary>
/// Uses default .net GIF encoding and adds animation headers.
/// </summary>
public class Gif : IDisposable, IEnumerable<Image>
{
    #region Header Constants
    const byte FileTrailer = 0x3b,
        ApplicationBlockSize = 0x0b,
        GraphicControlExtensionBlockSize = 0x04;

    const int ApplicationExtensionBlockIdentifier = 0xff21,
        GraphicControlExtensionBlockIdentifier = 0xf921;

    const long SourceGlobalColorInfoPosition = 10,
        SourceGraphicControlExtensionPosition = 781,
        SourceGraphicControlExtensionLength = 8,
        SourceImageBlockPosition = 789,
        SourceImageBlockHeaderLength = 11,
        SourceColorBlockPosition = 13,
        SourceColorBlockLength = 768;

    const string ApplicationIdentification = "NETSCAPE2.0",
        FileType = "GIF",
        FileVersion = "89a";
    #endregion

    class GifFrame
    {
        public GifFrame(Image image, double delay, int xOffset, int yOffset)
        {
            Image = image;
            Delay = delay;
            XOffset = xOffset;
            YOffset = yOffset;
        }

        public Image Image;
        public double Delay;
        public int XOffset, YOffset;
    }

    List<GifFrame> Frames = new List<GifFrame>();

    public Gif() { DefaultFrameDelay = 500; }

    public Gif(Stream InStream, int Repeat = 0, int Delay = 500)
    {
        using (Image Animation = Bitmap.FromStream(InStream))
        {
            int Length = Animation.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Time);

            DefaultFrameDelay = Delay;
            this.Repeat = Repeat;

            for (int i = 0; i < Length; ++i)
            {
                Animation.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Time, i);

                var Frame = new Bitmap(Animation.Size.Width, Animation.Size.Height);

                Graphics.FromImage(Frame).DrawImage(Animation, new Point(0, 0));

                Frames.Add(new GifFrame(Frame, Delay, 0, 0));
            }
        }
    }

    #region Properties
    public int DefaultWidth { get; set; }

    public int DefaultHeight { get; set; }

    public int Count { get { return Frames.Count; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default Delay in Milliseconds
    /// </summary>
    public int DefaultFrameDelay { get; set; }

    public int Repeat { get; private set; }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a frame to this animation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Image">The image to add</param>
    /// <param name="XOffset">The positioning x offset this image should be displayed at.</param>
    /// <param name="YOffset">The positioning y offset this image should be displayed at.</param>
    public void AddFrame(Image Image, double? frameDelay = null, int XOffset = 0, int YOffset = 0)
    {
        Frames.Add(new GifFrame(Image, frameDelay ?? DefaultFrameDelay, XOffset, YOffset));
    }

    public void AddFrame(string FilePath, double? frameDelay = null, int XOffset = 0, int YOffset = 0)
    {
        AddFrame(new Bitmap(FilePath), frameDelay, XOffset, YOffset);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int Index) { Frames.RemoveAt(Index); }

    public void Clear() { Frames.Clear(); }

    public void Save(Stream OutStream)
    {
        using (var Writer = new BinaryWriter(OutStream))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
            {
                var Frame = Frames[i];

                using (var gifStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    Frame.Image.Save(gifStream, ImageFormat.Gif);

                    // Steal the global color table info
                    if (i == 0) InitHeader(gifStream, Writer, Frame.Image.Width, Frame.Image.Height);

                    WriteGraphicControlBlock(gifStream, Writer, Frame.Delay);
                    WriteImageBlock(gifStream, Writer, i != 0, Frame.XOffset, Frame.YOffset, Frame.Image.Width, Frame.Image.Height);
                }
            }

            // Complete File
            Writer.Write(FileTrailer);
        }
    }

    #region Write
    void InitHeader(Stream sourceGif, BinaryWriter Writer, int w, int h)
    {
        // File Header
        Writer.Write(FileType.ToCharArray());
        Writer.Write(FileVersion.ToCharArray());

        Writer.Write((short)(DefaultWidth == 0 ? w : DefaultWidth)); // Initial Logical Width
        Writer.Write((short)(DefaultHeight == 0 ? h : DefaultHeight)); // Initial Logical Height

        sourceGif.Position = SourceGlobalColorInfoPosition;
        Writer.Write((byte)sourceGif.ReadByte()); // Global Color Table Info
        Writer.Write((byte)0); // Background Color Index
        Writer.Write((byte)0); // Pixel aspect ratio
        WriteColorTable(sourceGif, Writer);

        // App Extension Header
        unchecked { Writer.Write((short)ApplicationExtensionBlockIdentifier); };
        Writer.Write((byte)ApplicationBlockSize);
        Writer.Write(ApplicationIdentification.ToCharArray());
        Writer.Write((byte)3); // Application block length
        Writer.Write((byte)1);
        Writer.Write((short)Repeat); // Repeat count for images.
        Writer.Write((byte)0); // terminator
    }

    void WriteColorTable(Stream sourceGif, BinaryWriter Writer)
    {
        sourceGif.Position = SourceColorBlockPosition; // Locating the image color table
        var colorTable = new byte[SourceColorBlockLength];
        sourceGif.Read(colorTable, 0, colorTable.Length);
        Writer.Write(colorTable, 0, colorTable.Length);
    }

    void WriteGraphicControlBlock(Stream sourceGif, BinaryWriter Writer, double frameDelay)
    {
        sourceGif.Position = SourceGraphicControlExtensionPosition; // Locating the source GCE
        var blockhead = new byte[SourceGraphicControlExtensionLength];
        sourceGif.Read(blockhead, 0, blockhead.Length); // Reading source GCE

        unchecked { Writer.Write((short)GraphicControlExtensionBlockIdentifier); }; // Identifier
        Writer.Write((byte)GraphicControlExtensionBlockSize); // Block Size
        Writer.Write((byte)(blockhead[3] & 0xf7 | 0x08)); // Setting disposal flag
        Writer.Write((short)(frameDelay / 10)); // Setting frame delay
        Writer.Write((byte)blockhead[6]); // Transparent color index
        Writer.Write((byte)0); // Terminator
    }

    void WriteImageBlock(Stream sourceGif, BinaryWriter Writer, bool includeColorTable, int x, int y, int w, int h)
    {
        sourceGif.Position = SourceImageBlockPosition; // Locating the image block
        var header = new byte[SourceImageBlockHeaderLength];
        sourceGif.Read(header, 0, header.Length);
        Writer.Write((byte)header[0]); // Separator
        Writer.Write((short)x); // Position X
        Writer.Write((short)y); // Position Y
        Writer.Write((short)w); // Width
        Writer.Write((short)h); // Height

        if (includeColorTable) // If first frame, use global color table - else use local
        {
            sourceGif.Position = SourceGlobalColorInfoPosition;
            Writer.Write((byte)(sourceGif.ReadByte() & 0x3f | 0x80)); // Enabling local color table
            WriteColorTable(sourceGif, Writer);
        }
        else Writer.Write((byte)(header[9] & 0x07 | 0x07)); // Disabling local color table

        Writer.Write((byte)header[10]); // LZW Min Code Size

        // Read/Write image data
        sourceGif.Position = SourceImageBlockPosition + SourceImageBlockHeaderLength;

        var dataLength = sourceGif.ReadByte();
        while (dataLength > 0)
        {
            var imgData = new byte[dataLength];
            sourceGif.Read(imgData, 0, dataLength);

            Writer.Write((byte)dataLength);
            Writer.Write(imgData, 0, dataLength);
            dataLength = sourceGif.ReadByte();
        }

        Writer.Write((byte)0); // Terminator
    }
    #endregion

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Frames.Clear();
        Frames = null;
    }

    public Image this[int Index] { get { return Frames[Index].Image; } }

    public IEnumerator<Image> GetEnumerator() { foreach (var Frame in Frames) yield return Frame.Image; }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
}
```